# What is the best way to use EF 4 and DDD

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I would like to use EFf 4 as my ORM in my DDD project. I am going to generate my model based on my classes.  Should I create classes that are basically dto objects for my business objects to consumer or should I implement the actuall BO classes in my EF model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the EF model should be the business objects, otherwise you will just have another layer of abstraction that you will have to write plumbing code for.

Comment: I've created that other layer of abstraction on an EFv1 project, and it really isn't a good solution.

Comment: But what if i want to customize the "DB Model" for example i'm using localized tables in DB but want to represent this two tables to one Model in my BL. How to do that if i don't have my own BL Model ? i can't depend on EF Model because EF will give me two classes for this localized table !.